# Command loop for processing on a directory of images

Tags: image, loops, image-processing, cmd, converters

I have a program called GPU Debayer that converts images using this command-line code:

```
DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i inputpic.pgm -o outputpic.ppm
```

I was previously dealing with folders of images whose file names were the same except the ends were numbered 0-39.  As such, I was debayering the folders like this in cmd prompt.

```
for %a in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1
2 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
39) do DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i single%a.pgm -o si
ngle%a.ppm
```

Now, I need to deal with one folder holding many sets of these images now labled filename0000 - filename0039   But, there are, like I said, a few of these.  I.e., 120 images, 40 with the names "filename0000 - filename0039" , 40 named "filename25_0000 - filename25_0039" and 40 named "filename37_0000 - filename37_0039".

Is there any sort of way or loop to debayer ALL of these images with one script?  I have imagemagick on my machine.  And if anyone is familiar with the GPU Debayer, this is the tool i'm using.  It seems to have some sort of repeat function maybe?http://www.fastcompression.com/products/debayer/debayer.htm

Thanks for any ideas!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really have any real familiarity with that specific program, but I would suggest the following may accomplish that task (in a batch file):

```
setlocal
for %%i in (0,1,39) do (
    DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i filename00%%~i.pgm -o filename00%%~i.ppm
)
for %%i in (25 37) do (
    for %%~j in (0,1,39) do (
    DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i filename%%~i_00%%~j.pgm -o filename%%~i_00%%~j.ppm
    )
)
```

Just copy and paste this, and it basically automates the process you were doing. That last loop does any of the ones with numbers and underscores. Keep in mind: I don't know a lot about the batch processing whatever in this, and I don't know exactly how to recurse this through multiple named folders. Also, it might be possible to write something a little better using `forfiles`.

Comment: thanks so much, your loop is helpful, but your bringing my attention to the forfiles command is even more so!  I'm going to try to do it with forfiles (the names will always be dynamic, but the filetypes wont). I'm getting some errors, but i'll just post another question about them.  Thanks!